Present for a habit
I am asking you to sell me this record and I ask you this every year until you accept.
I am asking you to sell me this record and I  will be asking you this every year until you  accept .
I think both versions are grammatically correct  but the first seems stronger to me . I think present is possible here as asking this question  is going to be an habit .

"finish to accept" is incorrect. "until you agree" or "until you do" or "until you accept my offer".  The second clause (after "and") is a statement about the future.  The "asking" you do today is not the same "asking" that you will do in subsequent years; next year it will be a repeated action.   I am going to bed early tonight, and I willl be going to bed early the rest of the week as well.  Just because you have a plan for the entire week does not make it a single going-to-bed action.

A habit (the 'h' isn't silent).

Using simple present tense, no helping verbs, for future is most often used with "fixed events," things with a scheduled time, like "the train leaves at 8" or "I graduate in May." It isn't the best fit here.

Further to TimR's Comment, consider also '… until you finally accept…' which reads as though it may be the source of your confusion.
Please also note, 'I will be asking…' is and 'I ask…' is not correct.

As this is about future action, will be asking or will ask is better.  Also, we should delete finish to:

I am asking you to sell me this record, and I will be asking (or will ask)
you this every year until you accept (it).


but if I am asking now  it is not a future . It has started

The current asking is described in the first clause.  The second clause is about the future ones.

You'd only use the present tense if you asked last year (ongoing action).

What do you mean ? I don't understand

@YvesLefol Well, any ongoing action can have "both present and future." "I am driving now and will be driving for another hour." I'm honestly not sure what Stuart F meant. This example is tricky in one way because asking once is not an ongoing action, but we're making a pattern, so we can kind of talk about it in both ways. "I asked you last year; I'm asking now; and I will be asking every year."
